# error : given file does not exist : dictionary

Tags: android, jackcess

I added my **dictionary.accdb** file under `res/raw` and res directories though I'am getting given file does not exist : dictionary error

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
System.setProperty("com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.brokenNio","true");
System.setProperty("com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.resourcePath ","res/raw/");
Database database = null;
Table table = null;
try {
  database = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("dictionary.accdb"));
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and error log is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: given file does not exist: dictionary
```

Comment: Why do you guys never post the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Is it possibly because you are not referring to your res/raw correctly?

Comment: how to refer res/raw file?

Comment: your code and your exception don't agree.  please make sure you are executing the code that you think you are executing.